# How to detect new rows in Matlab cell arrays?

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I have a cell array with multiple rows which is updated over time. I want to compare an old version of the cell array with a new version and want to find out how many unique rows have not been part of the previous version. The complication is that a) unique rows are only defined by the properties of each cell in the row, b) rows can change the position while the cell array is being updated (e.g. row 4 can then be row 6 etc.).

Example:
Old version:
A =

```
[  3]    'blue'     [ 5]
'red'    [    5]    [ 6]
[  4]    'white'    [10]
```

New version:
A =

```
[8]    'yellow'    [ 3]
[4]    'white'     [10]
[3]    'blue'      [ 5]
```

In this case, we would see two changes: One row has been deleted, another one has been newly added.

How can I detect this easily via code?

Comment: Since the order of your rows might change, and even the columns, except the third column, perform the search according to the third column, `A{:,3}`.

Comment: not easily - is the structure of your cellarray [Double] [String] [Double] ? i.e. always 2 doubles and a string  - is any column ever fixed? or can they all change around.

Comment: Maybe you should make some sort of hash function that can each row into a unique key. This would depend on the constraints for each column but say each column ranges from 1 - 10 and you have fewer than 10 colours then your hash function could do something like `key = col1 + col2*10 + col3*100`, of course you would first need to convert your colours to integers but that's really not hard

Comment: Thanks for asking. Indeed, the columns are fixed (other than in my example). E.g. 2nd column is always string.

Comment: I really liked @Dan 's idea of creating a unique hash, you just have to change your colours to integers like 1 - 10 with each color being a unique colour, and then hash all 3 Ints together. You can use the Cantor pairing function if you want.